# How to create the following 3 col layout in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I create the following 3col layout where each left-content and right-content (not nav style) is fixed and the main middle content can contain a hero (or whatever content).

Variations:

1. middle content resizes with width of page
2. middle content is fixed max width

Need to test both because a chart and other widgets are going in the middle content view and need to see how they react to fixed size or allow to stretch.

Variant 1 - Middle content resizes

- On initial load

[image]

- Page resized..shrinked so body (Hello World) is auto adjusted.

[image]

Any info greatly appreciated!

Comment: please attach one more screenshot to illustrate how would it look when resize...

Comment: @SaurabhLP: hi, thx for the reply.  basically looking for the middle content to resize (That is variation number 1 per both illustrations above).  However, I'd be interested in if the middle being just fixed width as well.

Comment: i have two solution for this, one using table structure and one using custom css using div... what you want?

Comment: @SaurabhLP cool, I would rather more scaffolding/html/table structure than css.  However, perhaps you could post both just for literary content?

Comment: First you "said middle content should be fixed width since it will contain a chart." and 2 lines later you say "middle content resizes with width of page". From the screenshots I guess you want the resizable option?

Comment: @SaurabhLP yes, resize option but i'd like to see both.  the reason being is that a chart is going in that space and I need to test if it can resize or not.  Thx for replies...will test out today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a full screen layout, you have to use a container thats simply not a **bootstrap grid layout** because it will be **responsive** so your container will be adjust as far as screen resolution is consent...

**Using div and css:-**

```
.table { position:relative; }
.column { }
.column.left { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:300px; height:100%; }
.column.hero { margin:0 300px; }
.column.right { position:absolute; right:0; top:0; width:300px; height:100%; }
```

**html:-**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="column left">Left Sidebar</div>
    <div class="column hero">Hero Layout</div>
       <div class="column right">Right Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

**Demo:-** http://jsfiddle.net/VTwnt/1/

Thanks hope that work for you...

Comment: With these percentage values all the columns will resize with the browser size. I think he wants the left and right columns fixed and only the middle column to resize based on some max-wisth.

Comment: @PeteD may be you are right, i have done some changes above, it cant be possible in tables...

Comment: @SaurabhLP: thx for reply. however, this only stacked the divs -> http://bit.ly/14oVLhJ. that is normal/expanded view

Comment: @JaJ have a look at this demo i have created... http://jsfiddle.net/VTwnt/1/show/